# Accepted way to do Enum comparison

Tags: c#, enums

I'm sure this has probably been asked, but I can't seem to find the right answer...maybe just using the wrong search terms. Anyway, I have the following code;

```
if (e.Menu.Id.Equals(SchedulerMenuItemId.AppointmentMenu) ||
    e.Menu.Id.Equals(SchedulerMenuItemId.AppointmentDependencyMenu))
{ ... }
```

It seems a little redundant/duplicated to me. I can't use a bitwise OR though, as the enum isn't marked as `Flag`. I guess that's because there's 71 enum values defined and that's a bit beyond the Flag option...

Potentially I could do a switch and have the cases "fall through" which is maybe a little cleaner...

Is there any other way of doing a comparison such as the above (with extensibility and readability in mind), it may be more than just 2 comparisons.

Comment: this question could be worth asking at http://codereview.stackexchange.com, I am not sure if it is off-topic here but it is definitely on-topic there.

Comment: Perhaps the underlying issue is why do you have an flags enum with 71 individual options?

Comment: _"I guess that's because there's 71 enum values defined and that's a bit beyond the Flag option..."_ It is not that much about capacity. Bitwise OR is used for cases when enum values are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: 71 enums? that's a red flag not to use enums. May be have a XML file as a config file with all the menu options and you can parse the XML using LINQ to XML.

Comment: @pushpraj Duly noted. If there's not success here, I'll delete and move to code review.

Comment: @m-y It's not a flags enum, that's why I mentioned that I *can't* use a bitwise OR.

Comment: @DanKodi yeah, it's a lot...Not my code though, it's part of a library, so I can't do anything about that.

Comment: @FizzBuzz: The only reason you don't is because of the limitation on the number of possible flags. My point was that if you have the *need* to have an enum with 71 individual options, that in itself is most likely a large design issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use LINQ

```
var enums = new[]
        {
            SchedulerMenuItemId.AppointmentMenu
            SchedulerMenuItemId.AppointmentDependencyMenu
        };

if(enums.Any(x => (int)x == e.Menu.Id)) { }
```

Comment: +1. Note that `new HashSet {Value1, Value2,...}` would be faster in almost all cases.

Comment: Nice! That's a far better approach than my current one.